# If my Schengen visa insurance expires on the day of my departure?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, germany, insurance

It's my first time to Europe and I'll be applying for a Schengen visa. I bought a travel insurance. On my coverage letter, it says the expiration date is Aug 20th. However, that's the date of my departure from Europe. I'm worried that this might be a problem because the insurance expires on the day I leave. Technically, I'm still in Europe while waiting to board at the airport. Is this a serious problem? Can someone speak from experience about this kind of nitty-gritty problem? Should I extend my coverage duration?

Comment: What happens if your flight is delayed? Or you get taken ill on your way to the airport? Surely you'd want your insurance to last at least until you get home?

Comment: So true... thank you! Well if you didn't answer in the comment I couldve chosen you as the final answer! Anyway thanks!

Comment: What does your Schengen visa have to do with insurance?

Comment: @Flimzy having insurance is presumably a prerequisite to the visa application.  Elrohirrocks: Usually, insurance expires at the *end* of the expiration date, so if the expiration is 6/25, you are covered for things that happen on 6/25.  But Greg Hewgill's answer suggests a far better approach.  Anyway, your first step is probably to read the policy and see what its provisions would be should your return be delayed.

Comment: @phoog Thank you very much! I read the policy and decided to cancel the old insurance so I can buy a new one that covers more days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, travel insurance usually covers you until the date of your planned return home, or the *actual* date when you return home, whichever is later. This generally only applies if your delay is caused by something out of your control that is covered by your policy.

So, if you fall ill on the last day of your trip and have to be taken to hospital, your travel insurance should also cover the time you have been delayed. After all, that's what you bought it for.

I cannot recommend strongly enough that you *read* the fine print for your insurance policy so that you understand what it does and does not cover.

You should make sure your insurance end date is the date when you plan to actually step back into the front door of your house. Not, as you imply, the date when your flight departs from Europe.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've already purchased a new insurance covering the full range of my travel, and that includes the time when I step back into my front door! Really appreciate your answer!